# Akka Typed: Replying to messages (tell) sent from different actors

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

With Akka classic, one can easily implement a service (as an actor: ServiceActor) that

- receives requests from different actors (i.e., actors of different types: RequestorA, RequestorB, etc.),
- processes the request,
- sends back an acknowledgement to the requestor.

RequestorA sends a RequestMessage to the ServiceActor
ServiceActor sends back an Acknowledgement to RequestorA

Similarly, RequestorB sends a RequestMessage to the ServiceActor
ServiceActor sends back an Acknowledgement to RequestorB

Whatever the Requestor, there are only one type of RequestMessage and Acknowledgement and all the RequestMessages are handled the same way by the ServiceActor.

What is the way to achieve something similar with Akka Typed?
Now that the request message must contain an explicit replyTo: ActorRef[RequestorA.Message], is there a way to avoid implementing a different RequestMessage for each requestor?

- RequestFromRequestorA( replyTo: ActorRef[RequestorA.Message] )
- RequestFromRequestorB( replyTo: ActorRef[RequestorB.Message] )

Similarly, is there a way to avoid sending back a different type of acknowledgement to each type of requestor?

Comment: Why not just use the same request and response message types for all Requestors (with requests like `RequestFromAnyRequestor(replyTo: ActorRef[ResponseToAnyRequestor])`)?

Comment: Hi @MartinHH, I guess all the messages receives by all the requestors could inherit the same trait.  But is this a clean solution given that these Requestors have very different Behaviors despite the fact that they call this common service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically in Akka Typed, the response message is defined by the protocol of the actor handling the request, for instance (in Scala):

```scala
object MyActor {
  sealed trait Command

  case class Request(replyTo: ActorRef[Response]) extends Command

  sealed trait Response

  // and so forth
}
```

It then becomes the responsibility of the actor sending the `Request` to arrange to handle the `Response`.  If the requesting actor happens to only exist to send requests, it can define itself as a `Behavior[Response]`, but in the more general case, there are a couple of tactics that can be used.

The actor can set up a message adapter:

```scala
val responseRef = context.messageAdapter { response =>
  // convert to this actor's message protocol
  ???
}

otherActor ! MyActor.Request(responseRef)
```

If doing this, it's generally a good idea to set up the `responseRef` only once (e.g. in `Behaviors.setup`).

If the actor is just going to be performing the request once or only ever expects one response per request (and expects that response in a bounded amount of time), the "ask pattern" may be clearer:

```scala
implicit val timeout: Timeout = 15.seconds
context.ask(otherActor, MyActor.Request(_)) {
  case Success(resp) =>
    // convert to this actor's message protocol
    ???

  case Failure(ex) =>
    // convert to this actor's message protocol
    ???
```

This does require you to define an explicit timeout and handle the case where no response is received in time.  The `ActorRef` injected into the `Request` message is ephemeral: it will not receive any message beyond the first message sent to it nor will it receive a message after the timeout.

It is also possible to define an actor's behavior as a `Behavior[Any]` (which is like a "classic" untyped actor) but not expose that fact outside of the actor.  In Scala, this is fairly straightforward and safe to do thanks to contravariance:

```
Behaviors.setup[Any] { context =>
  // context.self is an ActorRef[Any], which by contravariance is usable as any type of ActorRef
  otherActor ! MyActor.Request(context.self)

  Behaviors.receiveMessage {
    case resp: MyActor.Response =>
      // handle response directly
      ???

    case _ =>
      Behaviors.unhandled
  }
}.narrow[Command]
```

The spawned `ActorRef` will be an `ActorRef[Command]` (i.e. only promise to handle `Command`), but the actor is able to decide to promise to handle any message it wants to handle (even if not a `Command`).  This does opt you out of compiler assistance when it comes to this actor sending messages to itself; additionally, this may be a bit of an obscure pattern, so its use should be well-commented.